# How to read standard input continuously?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C/C++: Capture characters from standard input without waiting for enter to be pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421860/c-c-capture-characters-from-standard-input-without-waiting-for-enter-to-be-pr)

Is there a way to read standard input **continuously**? I want to make an X and O game and I want the player to use the the arrows to move its position on the grid. I can't use `cin` because it requests you to press enter to get the input data into variables. So, does a function or an object doing that exist?

Comment: There's no platform-independent method.

Comment: This explains how to do it in a console application for both Windows and Linux:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421860/c-c-capture-characters-from-standard-input-without-waiting-for-enter-to-be-pr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For console (text) applications you'd use something like ncurses, which does terminal 'GUI' controls.

For graphics applications you would use something like SDL which enables event-driven programming.